# HTML/CSS не проигрывать анимацию для внутреннего класса

Tags: html, css

допустим есть div который при помощи анимации CSS "крутится" без остановки. Внутри него есть div с текстом который так же крутится. Возможно ли сделать так чтобы дочерний div "стоял" на месте и был исключен из анимации при помощи CSS?

Answer (score 10):

Вариант с использованием псевдоэлемента

Пример

```css
*{
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.circle{
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 text-align: center;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center; 
 position: relative; 
}
.circle:before{
 content: '';
 position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 border: 2px solid #ccc;
 border-right-color: #f00;
 border-radius: 50%;
 animation: rotate 1s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes rotate{
 0%{
  transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
 100%{
  transform: rotate(360deg);
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
 <div class="circle__text">
  Text
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Можно задать дочернему элементу аналогичное кручение в обратную сторону - тогда будет казаться, что он стоит на месте:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 70px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  animation: rotatediv 5s linear infinite;
}

p {
  animation: rotatep 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rotatediv {
  from { transform: rotate(0deg);}
  to { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes rotatep {
  from { transform: rotate(0deg);}
  to { transform: rotate(-360deg); }
}
```

```html
<div>
<p>
текст внутри дива
</p>
</div>
```